# waf cross-project dependencies

Tags: waf, build-system

I have a trivial waf project:

```
$ root
|-- a
|   `-- wscript
|-- b
|   `-- wscript
`-- wscript
```

Root wscript is

```py
def configure(conf):
    pass

def build(bld):
    bld.recurse('a b')
```

`a` wscript is

```py
def build(bld):
    bld (rule = 'touch ${TGT}', target = 'a.target' )
```

`b` wscript is

```py
def build(bld):
    bld (rule = 'cp ${SRC} ${TGT}', source='a.target', target='b.target')
```

What I'm trying to achieve is have a build system that first touches `a.target`, then copies it to `b.target`. I want to have rules for `a.target` and `b.target` to stay in their respective `wscript` files.

When I'm trying to launch it, I get the following error instead:

```
source not found: 'a.target' in bld(target=['b.target'], idx=1, tg_idx_count=2, meths=['process_rule', 'process_source'], rule='cp ${SRC} ${TGT}', _name='b.target', source='a.target', path=/<skip>/waf_playground/b, posted=True, features=[]) in /<skip>/waf_playground/b
```

If I put both rules into a single `wscript` file, everything works like a charm.

Is there a way for a target to depend on a another target defined in other `wscript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify source/target, that is expressed relative to the current `wscript` file.

```
$ waf configure build
...
source not found: 'a.target' in bld(source='a.target, ...)
...
$ tree build
build/
├── a
│   └── a.target
...
```

Knowing that, the fix is to refer to the `a.target` source file correctly in `b/wscript`:

```py
def build(bld):
    bld (rule = 'cp ${SRC} ${TGT}', source='../a/a.target', target='b.target')
```

The task now correctly finds the source file:

```
$ waf build
Waf: Entering directory `.../build'
[1/2] Creating build/a/a.target
[2/2] Compiling build/a/a.target
Waf: Leaving directory `.../build'
'build' finished successfully (0.055s)
$ tree build
build/
├── a
│   └── a.target
├── b
│   └── b.target
...
```